# JPanel is not draw on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Linked to a previous question : I want to draw on panel. I have the following classes:

**GMain.java**

```
public class GMain{
    static frmDashboard fDB;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    fDB = new frmDashboard();
    fDB.setTitle("Graphics Mate");
    fDB.setVisible(true);
    fDB.pack();
    }
}
```

**frmDashboard.java**

```
    public class frmDashboard extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        public frmDashboard() {
            initComponents();
            Clear();
        }

        private void btnPlotActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
            frmCPlot fCP = new frmCPlot();
            fCP.setVisible(true);
            fCP.pack();
          }
      }
```

**frmCPlot.java**

```
      public class frmCPlot extends javax.swing.JFrame {
          int W, H;
          int N;

          public frmCPlot() {
              initComponents();
              CPanel cp = new CPanel();
              this.getContentPane().add(cp);
             System.out.println("WW = " + cp.getWidth() + 
                           "    HH = " + cp.getHeight());
     }

     class CPanel extends JPanel{
         int i, j;

         public CPanel(){
             setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
             setBackground(Color.WHITE);
         }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
              super.paintComponent(g);
              g.drawLine(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
       }
    }
}
```

The frmCPlot is displayed, but CPanel is not displayed. Not talking about the line. More, the output from the **frmCPlot.java** is:

```
   *WW = 0  HH = 0*
```

I followed the instructions by the book. I tried to add a repaint in frmCPlot class, in CPanel class, but no use. Have any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's never a good idea to extend a JFrame as it's a **Top Level Component**. This will just lead to more problems. You should, instead, create a class that extends a `JPanel` and add that to the a JFrame. A `JPanel` is good for when you want to group things together. Since you still have to have a JFrame somewhere in your program (or else it will display nothing) you'll have to make a variable instead and add the `JPanel` to it.

Try something like this

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Frame");
frame.setSize(500, 500);
frame.getContentPane().add(new JPanel MyPanel);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanx. Works. My GUI is in Netbeans.Why I have to write all this stuff, when in netbeans is have only to add in design JPanel to JFrame ? i.e what s the reason for which things don't go in netbeans so I have to write code?

Comment: @EbticBobo I think you mean that Netbeans is your IDE or programming environment ;). Or did you mean that you created your GUI in Netbeans? And I'm not quite sure if you're talking about code completion (where it helps you finish lines of code by predicting it), or something else. But whether you're using Netbeans or or Eclipse is irrelevant in many cases.